# SQL Logic to extract information

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation where I need to extract information from a sql table row.
A typical string looks like,

```
RMR*AZ*10001312**119.76
```

where `RMR` is the key to identify the row. I need to extract information between second and third `*`, i.e. `10001312` and after fourth one i.e. is `119.76`

This information will be populated in a table.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: **What** database system, and which version?? **SQL** is just the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: Shouldn't you be storing all of that info in separate columns instead of as one long string?

Comment: That's an EDI 820 document.  Let me guess: someone wrote their own EDI parser and this is the output.   The SEGMENT is the RMR, and the ELEMENTS are the values in between the *.  If you're on SQL Server try a SPLIT function like this: http://sqltutorials.blogspot.com/2007/09/sql-function-split.html.

Comment: OBL - how in the world do you know which document that record is referring to?  If that is all the information in the row, it is pretty useless because there's no key to relate it to the actual document.

Comment: Thanks every one for the help. I got it. Andrew impressive of you to figure out the file type. I guess you work in the medicare field too?

Comment: Glad people here have been of help to you. Please give them the respect they deserve by upvoting their answer(s) and accept one of the answers.

Comment: @OBL - EDI is standard across many industries.  I've been doing EDI for almost 15 years.  The 820 is commonly used, so the RMR segment tipped me off.  It seems all the EDI questions on SO are from people using BizTalk (somewhat difficult to use) or reinventing the wheel completely and writing their own solution.  As James said, if you used an answer below, please mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example done in SQL server, which may help you.

```
declare @myString varchar(50)
set @myString = 'sadfa*lkj*234r2*'

declare @startPosition int
declare @endPosition int

--First * location
select @startPosition = Charindex('*', @myString, 0)

--Second * location
select @endPosition = Charindex('*', @myString, @startPosition+1)
select @endPosition 

select substring(@myString, 
    @startPosition +1 ,
    @endPosition - @startPosition -1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that there are no built-in SQL functions (that I know of) to parse a string like you want to, I would suggest using a user-defined function. Then you can split your string on `*` and get out the indexes which you care about.

The thread [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648) has some extensive discussion and many examples of such functions.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your database engine. For DB2 I implemented this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10175295/1336443

Answer (score 0):

Well, you haven't said which one of SQL dialects you need, so just a generic answer: use SQL's string operations, for example look here: http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-substring.html