# SQL how to subtract float time and string time? 

Tags: sql, db2

Table DB2

```
ID       HOURS        HOURSMINUTES       
1000     480.5        30:30:00
```

I want to get HOURS - HOURSMINUTES

```
ID       HOURS - HOURSMINUTES
1000       450.0
```

HOURS is float value in HOURS- so 480.5 hours. HOURSMINUTES is string value: 30:30:00 (30hours 30minutes 00 seconds)

How to subtract?

This is my full expression because I am getting values from two tables (I get them in this format but I can not subtract) . I am getting HOURS already as subtraction from two timestamp formats - result is in float. cumulativetime is string value.

```
select t1.id,
dec (( timestampdiff(
  4, 
  char(t1.actualfinish - t1.reportdate))/60.00),10,2) as HOURS,t2.cumulativetime as HOURSMINUTES
from t1
join t2 on t2.id=t1.id
```

When I try to insert solution below I am getting an error.

```
    select t1.id,
    dec (( timestampdiff(
      4, 
      char(t1.actualfinish - t1.reportdate))/60.00),10,2) as HOURS,t2.cumulativetime as HOURSMINUTES,

dec (( timestampdiff(
      4, 
      char(t1.actualfinish - t1.reportdate))/60.00),10,2)- cast(substr(t2.cumulativetime, 1, 2) as int) - 
      (cast(substr(t2.cumulativetime, 4, 2) as int) / 60.0) as diff
    from t1
    join t2 on t2.id=t1.id
```

I tried also Kapil version:

```
select t1.id,
    dec (( timestampdiff(
      4, 
      char(t1.actualfinish - t1.reportdate))/60.00),10,2) as HOURS,t2.cumulativetime as HOURSMINUTES,

(dec (( timestampdiff(
  4, 
  char(t1.actualfinish - t1.reportdate))/60.00),10,2) - (CAST(substr(t2.cumulativetime , 1, 2) AS float) + CAST(substr(t2.cumulativetime , 4, 2) AS float)/60 + CAST(substr(t2.cumulativetime , 7, 2) AS float)/3600)) as diff

from t1
    join t2 on t2.id=t1.id
```

Comment: can you try this?

 `select t1.id,
   dec (( timestampdiff(4, char(t1.actualfinish - t1.reportdate))/60.00),10,2) as HOURS,
   t2.cumulativetime as HOURSMINUTES,
   cast(substr(t2.cumulativetime, 1, 2) as int) as hhdif,
   (cast(substr(t2.cumulativetime, 4, 2) as int) / 60.0) as mmdiff
 from t1 join t2 on t2.id=t1.id`

please post the output or error message

Comment: paul I succeded problem was that one value in my column was 512:30:30 so with substr (1,2) (4,2) it was taking the not valid value (":" was includeded). So how to solve this then? To always be applicable no meter how decimal places will take hours in HOURSMINUTES column? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
select HOURS - 
       cast(substr(HOURSMINUTES, 1, 2) as int) - 
      (cast(substr(HOURSMINUTES, 4, 2) as int) / 60.0) as diff
```

Comment: op tagged DB2, so `substr` instead of `substring`

Comment: My HOURSMINUTES column in this case starts with 30 (two decimal places) but I have in table values with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 decimal places then I can not use this query because ":" will be in part for subtraction as float value which is not valid

Comment: how then to solve this to be unique with all values for hours in HOURSMINUTES column?

Comment: Then you can use [this split function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305804/split-a-varchar-in-db2-to-retrieve-a-value-inside) to find the correct parts of your time string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Select  (HOURS - (CAST(substr(HOURSMINUTES , 1, 2) AS float) + CAST(substr(HOURSMINUTES , 4, 2) AS float)/60 + CAST(substr(HOURSMINUTES , 7, 2) AS float)/3600)) as diff
From table
```

Comment: My HOURSMINUTES column in this case starts with 30 (two decimal places) but I have in table values with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 decimal places then I can not use this query because ":" will be in part for subtraction as float value which is not valid

Comment: how then to solve this to be unique with all values for hours in HOURSMINUTES column?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using DB2 for z/OS version 9.1 in compatibility mode:

```
select
  t.HRS
  - cast(substr(t.HMS, 1, locate(':', t.HMS) - 1) as FLOAT)
  - (cast(substr(t.HMS, locate(':', t.HMS) + 1, locate(':', t.HMS, locate(':', t.HMS) + 1) - locate(':', t.HMS) - 1) as FLOAT) / 60.0)
  - (cast(substr(t.HMS, locate(':', t.HMS, locate(':', t.HMS, locate(':', t.HMS) + 1)) + 1) as FLOAT) / 3600.0)
from
  (
    select
      cast(480.5 as float) as HRS
      , '333:44:55' as HMS
    from
      sysibm.SYSDUMMY1
  ) as t
with ur for read only;
```

This gives a result of `146.75138888888887`.

If you have [`LOCATE_IN_STRING`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_bif_locateinstring.htm) available, you can use that to simplify finding the n-th `:` in the `HMS` string.