# DB2 splitting comma separated String to use in a IN clause.. Update: WITH clause query inside IN clause

Tags: string, db2

I have a table `TableA` with values in `ColumnA` as below:

```
ColumnA
__________________
a,b,c
d,e
```

I have table TableB with values as:

```
ColumnB     ColumnC
____________________
a            1
b            2
c            3
d            4
e            5
x            9
```

I want to use above values in another query:

```
SELECT columnC FROM TableB where ColumnB in (select ColumnA from TableA)
```

Obviously above query won't work.

The output should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

How to do this without function i.e. in a simple query?

Update:

Based on mustoccio's comment below, I made it work using the WITH clause:

```
With split_data as (select ColumnA as split_string, ',' as split from TableA),
rec
(
   split_string, split, row_num, column_value, pos
)
as
(
   select
   split_string,
   split,
   1,
   varchar(substr(split_string, 1, decode(instr(split_string, split, 1),0,length(split_string), instr(split_string, split, 1)-1)), 255),
   instr(split_string, split, 1) + length(split)
   from split_data
   union
   all
   select
   split_string,
   split,
   row_num+1,
   varchar(substr(split_string, pos, decode(instr(split_string, split, pos),0, length(split_string)-pos+1, instr(split_string, split, pos)-pos)), 255),
   instr(split_string, split, pos)+length(split)
   from rec
   where row_num < 300000
   and pos > length(split)
)
select
column_value as data
from rec
order by row_num
```

However, when I try to use above query inside the IN clause of my query:

```
SELECT columnC FROM TableB where ColumnB in (/* WITH query here */)
```

I get error as:

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=as;in ( With split_data;JOIN, DRIVER=3.50.152
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, SQLERRMC=2;-104;42601;as|in ( With split_data|JOIN, DRIVER=3.50.152
SQLState:  56098
ErrorCode: -727
```

Can't we use WITH clause query inside IN clause ?
If NO, what is the solution ?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367069/how-to-transform-comma-separated-column-into-multiples-rows-in-db2/28596102#28596102

Comment: @mustaccio: The link in the answer doesn't open here! :( would it be possible to post the code as an answer below please ?

Comment: You may want to check the syntax diagram for `SELECT` in the manual. CTE is always at the beginning of the statement: `with foo(bar) as (...) select x from y where z in (select bar from foo)`

Answer (score -1):

Inner join must work here.. you can use this one

select columnC from tableB inner join tableA on  tableB.columnB=tableA.columnA;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgtAy.png)

you can see the result here

Comment: Someone downvoted your answer because its incorrect. TableA is not in the way you have depicted in your answer image. TableA has comma separated values as mentioned in the question.