# Can we do the same with a comma separated field to multiple columns in a SQLRPGLE?

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400, rpgle

Can we parse a comma separated string which comes from a 3rd party and move to multiple columns of a file in SQLRPGLE
Say we have a field that contains    MFG,9876,,0001,123435   to   multiple columns  Site = MFG  , Parent Item = 9876, revision = ‘ ‘,  sequence = 0001, component Item= 12345  etc. ?

Comment: Can be done with some changes to the answer of this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367069/how-to-transform-comma-separated-column-into-multiples-rows-in-db2

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the CSV file, store it in the IFS. Then it is a simple operation to use the `CPYFRMIMPF` command to load the file into a database file.

Comment: CPYFRMIMPF is ok for a one time thing if the CSV is perfect.  If either of those is not the case, consider using the IFS API's to read and parse the CSV yourself.

Comment: `CPYFRMIMPF` is great for automation, and isn't all that temperamental. Yes you can write your own parser, but if the built in parser works, why go through the effort of writing your own. That seems to be similar to premature optimization.

Answer (score -3):

Insert CSV into table with SQL.
create string and execute immediate.

```
mstring = 'insert into mytable (col1, col2 , col3) values (' + mydata + ')';

exec immediate :mystring;
```

Comment: Take the `:` off `:mydata`, and this might work if string values are quoted properly. But I would view this as somewhat dangerous in an SQL Injection context.