# DB2 Comma Separated values into columns

Tags: db2, db2-400, db2-luw

In My table have values as below

Need separate column for each comma

```
Select Element from Test_check

Element:
Test,Sample,Maiden

Expected Result :

Element:
Test
Sample
Maiden
```

Comment: [Duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961996/how-to-split-a-string-value-based-on-a-delimiter-in-db2/61540876?r=SearchResults#61540876)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to transform comma separated column into multiples rows in db2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367069/how-to-transform-comma-separated-column-into-multiples-rows-in-db2)

Answer (score 1):

2 options, depending on what you are trying to do.

1. SP [COMMA_TO_TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0055160.html) (available only on 10.1 and higher on LUW)
2. **Recursive Query**

This could be one option

```
CREATE TABLE TLIST (ID  INTEGER, LISTVALUES VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO TLIST VALUES(1, '10,11,12,13,14,15')
INSERT INTO TLIST VALUES(2, '25,26,27,28,29')

select * from tlist

ID          LISTVALUES
----------- ------------------
          1 10,11,12,13,14,15
          2 25,26,27,28,29   

WITH pquery (ID, wordnum, word, remainder)
AS
(
  SELECT base.ID, 1, 
    CASE WHEN LOCATE (',', LISTVALUES) > 0 THEN 
      SUBSTR (LISTVALUES, 1, LOCATE (',', LISTVALUES) - 1)
    ELSE
      LISTVALUES
    END word,
    CASE WHEN locate (',', LISTVALUES) > 0 THEN
      LTRIM (SUBSTR (LISTVALUES, LOCATE (',', LISTVALUES) + 1))
    ELSE
      NULL
    END remainder
  FROM TLIST base 
  
  UNION ALL
  
  SELECT ID, wordnum + 1, 
    CASE WHEN LOCATE (',', remainder) > 0 then 
      SUBSTR (remainder, 1, LOCATE (',', remainder) - 1)
    ELSE
      remainder
    END word,
    CASE WHEN LOCATE (',', remainder) > 0 THEN
      LTRIM (SUBSTR (remainder, LOCATE (',', remainder) + 1))
    ELSE
      NULL
    END remainder
  FROM pquery t0
  WHERE (t0.remainder IS NOT NULL )
    AND (wordnum < 100)
)
SELECT ID, WORD FROM pquery pq order by ID , wordnum;


ID          WORD      
----------- ----------
          1 10        
          1 11        
          1 12        
          1 13        
          1 14        
          1 15        
          2 25        
          2 26        
          2 27        
          2 28        
          2 29
```

*P.S. the predicate `(wordnum < 100)` in WHERE clause is required to avoid infinite loop, but off-course you can change the limit.*

Regards
Samuel Pizarro