# DB2 - String operations

Tags: db2

Can we check a string value with comma separated exists in another comma separated string in DB2?

I have say two string like below

```
Case-1:
String-1:'ABC,XYZ,PQR'
Srting-2:'MNO,PQR'
```

I want to have any function in DB2 which should return 1 in the above case as PQR from String-2 exists in String-1. The value should match any string within comma or after or before comma.

```
Case-2:
String-1:'ABC,XYZ,PQR'
Srting-2:'MNO,P QR'
```

But for the above case the same function should return 0. As there is space after "P"

I also want to have a similar function which should return the concatenated string but removes duplicates.

```
Case-1:
String-1:'ABC,XYZ,PQR'
Srting-2:'MNO,PQR'

Output should be 'ABC,XYZ,PQR,MNO' .
```

The order in comma separated values doesn't matter in this case; but PQR should not be repeated twice.

```
Case-2:
String-1:'ABC,XYZ,PQR'
Srting-2:'MNO,P QR'

In this case output should be 'ABC,XYZ,PQR,MNO,P QR' .
```

I am trying to achieve this using SQL or any function in DB2.

There is another case where I want to remove matching part of the string

```
Case-3:
String-1:'ABC,XYZ,PQR'
Srting-2:'MNO,PQR'

Output should be 'ABC,XYZ,MNO'
```

Obviously String-1 and String-2 can have any number of values separated by comma.

Comment: Which string functions did you look at? There are several, including REGEX-based. Please add your SQL query which has the problems. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You have to spit the values as rows then combine the lists with `INTERSECT` or `UNION` or `EXCEPT` depending on the output you want, then `LISTAGG` to get back to comma separated values. Like @data_henrik said there is multiple ways to split string with DB2. DB2 for IBM i has a specific function, so please also tag your question with the specific implementation of DB2 you use.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24367069/how-to-transform-comma-separated-column-into-multiples-rows-in-db2/24368140#24368140) should give you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLITTER (P_STR VARCHAR(4000), P_DELIM VARCHAR(10))
RETURNS TABLE (SEQ INT, TOKEN VARCHAR(50))
RETURN
SELECT TOK.SEQ, TOK.TOKEN
FROM XMLTABLE
(
  'for $id in tokenize($s, $t) return <i>{string($id)}</i>' PASSING P_STR AS "s", P_DELIM AS "t"
  COLUMNS
    SEQ   FOR ORDINALITY
  , TOKEN VARCHAR(50) PATH '.'
) TOK;

SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN EXISTS 
  (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM TABLE (SPLITTER ('ABC,XYZ,PQR', ',')) A
  JOIN TABLE (SPLITTER ('MNO,PQR', ',')) B ON B.TOKEN = A.TOKEN
  )
  THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;

SELECT LISTAGG (TOKEN, ',')
FROM
(
SELECT TOKEN
FROM TABLE (SPLITTER ('ABC,XYZ,PQR', ','))
  UNION
SELECT TOKEN
FROM TABLE (SPLITTER ('MNO,PQR', ','))
);

SELECT LISTAGG (TOKEN, ',')
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT COALESCE (A.TOKEN, B.TOKEN) AS TOKEN
  FROM TABLE (SPLITTER ('ABC,XYZ,PQR', ',')) A
  FULL JOIN TABLE (SPLITTER ('MNO,PQR', ',')) B ON B.TOKEN = A.TOKEN
  WHERE A.TOKEN IS NULL OR B.TOKEN IS NULL
);
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=28e9f0cec38a5233ad5b4278292dd93b) link.

Comment: What is P_STR in your function. I want to user both string values as input fo the function, so why there is only one? Also I can see you have used the hard coded string in the function. Can this use the variable?

Comment: I created a generic function splitting any delimited string passed with P_STR, and delimiter used with P_DELIM. This convenient function is used multiple times afterwards (in 3 last queries which are stand-alone queries and not part of this function). I haven't created any other functions you asked for presuming, that it's easy to create them based on queries I've provided.