# How to split value of a VARCHAR column for every 2 charactes in System i Navigator (AS/400)

Tags: db2, user-defined-functions, iseries-navigator

First of all, hi everyone, I hope you're having a great day.
So here's my problem.
I have a column in my table that consist of values all append together like

> 1120304050607080

I need to get this value and then split it into many 2 digit values so i can use them in another query like

> WHERE model in ('11,20,30,40,50,60,70,80') ...

Is this possible to do in a Db2 iSeries Navigator query ? If not, is there another way around ?

Thanks
Have a great day !

**EDIT:** Seems like the solution will be to do a function. I haven't done a function in iseries before so if anyone is willing to help, i'll take it !

Comment: What about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961996/how-to-split-a-string-value-in-db2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but i do not have a mark symbol to tell me when to split, it must be done every 2 characters. This solution seems to work only if you have a marker like '-' in the case of the link you put ? Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: What version of the OS are you using? There are regular expressions in the latest releases of DB2 for i.

Comment: Yes, I did notice that. I am looking at the repeat function to see if there is a way to avoid a loop. However, you may be stuck with a look if there isn't a built in function I can pass an expression of n+2 for length of the string.

Comment: @JohnKuhns : i got IBM System i Acces for Windows Version 7 Release 1 Modification Level 0.

Comment: @jsh : i did look at the scalar function link, but i do not see if any of these can be useful in my case. My only thought was if I could use SUBSTR for some "loop" like you said and it could extract first and second character together, then the third and fourth, etc.

Comment: Do all the rows have the same number of values?

Comment: Hi @Charles, it's a unique row. I need to get this particular row because it contains all "product numbers" (that's how we call them here). These numbers need to be in a WHERE condition to be able to get some other data. Getting the row is easy, but formatting it the way i need is the part i have no idea on how to do it. Hope this helps.

Comment: To resume my problem, i need to put some ',' between each pair of characters except the last one from a particular row in a table so i can use them in a where condition to get data from another table.

Comment: So you only have 1 row in which to split?

Comment: @Charles : Yes. I can get the value of the row, but it need to be formatted so i can use it in a "WHERE IN('')" condition with every value separated by a comma.

Comment: @Kaptin - You need _some_ sort of loop, there's no way around it.  There isn't generally a `SPLIT` function in SQL because using it means you're (usually) doing something wrong.  Outside of some very specific circumstances, you shouldn't be storing concatenated values like this.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse : I wish it was done differently but it has been implanted like this way before i was even born ;) 
Do you know any way to use a loop here because it is way over my knowledge with iseries db2.