# Function DB2 Table Function

Tags: sql, db2, pipe

Does someone knows how can I get that result bellow in DB2?

Query

```
Example : 

    SELECT * FROM TABLE(FunctionName('1||2||3',||)) ;
```

First one are parameters with values and second one is delimiter.

Result:

```
    Column

    1
    2
    3
```

Values that I put on that query are based on parameters and delimiters.

As I said above, rows is break by Pipe. I dont have huge background on PL/SQL.

Im using DB2 v11.1

Comment: Do you mean ` SELECT * FROM TABLE(FunctionName('1||2||3','||')) ;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961996/how-to-split-a-string-value-based-on-a-delimiter-in-db2

Answer (score 1):

So ive been facing that problem , and i found a solution for it :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Test(
Data_1 CLOB(1M), Delimtator VARCHAR(12))
RETURNS TABLE (
FieldData varchar(2048))
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
    DECLARE dInic INTEGER DEFAULT 1 ;
    DECLARE dFim  INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ;
    DECLARE Rowid1 INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE Campo VARCHAR(2048);

    IF Data_1 IS NULL THEN
        RETURN;
    END IF;

    SET dFim=LOCATE(Delimtator,Data_1);

    WHILE dFim>0 DO
     SET Campo=SUBSTRING(Data_1,dInic,dFim-dInic);
        PIPE (Campo);
        SET dInic=dFim+LENGTH(Delimtator);
        SET dFim=LOCATE(Delimtator,Data_1,dFim+LENGTH(Delimtator));
    END WHILE;

    SET Campo=SUBSTRING(Data_1, dInic,LENGTH(Data_1)-dInic+1);
    PIPE (Campo);
    RETURN;
END@
```

Comment: I like that you did this.  Could you comment the code.