# Convert varchar to timestamp and then add the time group by by ticketid

Tags: sql, db2

I need to convert a string value containing time in HH:MM:SS format to timestamp and then add those timestamps grouped by ticketid. I have tried TIME functions but they are not helping much.

Current results:

```
    TICKETID               WORKTIMETRACKING


       5141                  02:55:00
       5141                  00:00:00
       7856                  01:12:55
       7857                  00:07:00
       7857                  00:01:00
```

Desired results:

```
    TICKETID               WORKTIMETRACKING


       5141                  02:55:00
       7856                  01:12:55
       7857                  00:08:00
```

In current results we have same ticketids with different worktimetraking but I need to extract results by summing the time(in timestampformat) as shown in desired results (ticket:7857 worktime adds up to 00:08:00)

Comment: Even if you convert your character values to `TIME`, you cannot add one `TIME` value to another; you can only add a _duration_ (or interval) to `TIME`. Since what you're dealing with are duration values, that's what you need to work with.

Comment: is there a way to add time durations in db2?

Comment: Hi  please see [sqlserver_dateadd](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_dateadd.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query - SUM duration values (hh:mm:ss) from ALN field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746132/sql-query-sum-duration-values-hhmmss-from-aln-field)

Answer (score 1):

We cannot add two TIME values, i.e.

```
db2 "values time('00:01:59') + time ('00:00:02')"
SQL0402N  The data type of an operand of an arithmetic function or operation 
"+" is invalid.  SQLSTATE=42819
```

So the easiest approach would be to use [MIDNIGHT_SECONDS scalar function](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000827.html).

For your input

```
db2 "create table tickets(ticketid int, worktimetracking varchar(10))"
db2 "insert into tickets values (5141, '02:55:00')"
db2 "insert into tickets values (5141, '00:00:00')"
db2 "insert into tickets values (7856, '01:12:55')"
db2 "insert into tickets values (7857, '00:07:00')"
db2 "insert into tickets values (7857, '00:01:00')"
```

you can try something like this:

```
db2 "select 
       ticketid, 
       time('00:00:00') + sum(midnight_seconds(time(worktimetracking))) seconds as total_time 
     from 
       tickets 
     group 
       by ticketid"

TICKETID    TOTAL_TIME
----------- ----------
       5141 02:55:00  
       7856 01:12:55  
       7857 00:08:00  

  3 record(s) selected.
```

This would to as long as it is never more then 24 hours, otherwise you need a different type.

Comment: This is clever.

Comment: Hi @kkuduk.
Thanks alot for the answer. I'll try this for sure.
But worktimetracking will have more than 24 hours. What type would be used to cater that?

Comment: @Sarshad you can of course leave it it seconds. What you would like to see on the screen with e.g. 100 hours? "100:00:00"? Or something of a "4 days 4 hours" kind?

Comment: Also, your input data is in HH:MM:SS format. Does it ever exceed 24 hours for a single entry? Or only after aggregation?