# Get Substrings From DB2 Column

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I Have: AAAA/DATA1/Data2;xyx;pqr
this data 
I want only:**DATA1** And **Data2**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is for a specific row, maybe use `SUBSTR`? Something like

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTR(column, 6, 5) AS col1
, SUBSTR(column, 13, 5) AS col2
 FROM table
```

Here is something else you can do.. Although it gets pretty complicated, and this isn't the exact answer you are looking for but it will get you started. Hope this helps:

```
WITH test AS (
SELECT characters
  FROM ( VALUES
  (   'AAAA/DATA1/Data2;xyx;pqr'
  ) )
    AS testing(characters)
)
SELECT 
    SUBSTR(characters, 1, LOCATE('/', characters) - 1) AS FIRST_PART
  , SUBSTR(characters, LOCATE('/', characters) + 1) AS SECOND_PART
  , SUBSTR(characters, LOCATE('/', characters, LOCATE('/', characters) + 1) + 1) 
      AS THIRD_PART
    FROM test
;
```

DB2 does not have a single function for this, unfortunately. Check out this answer here: [How to split a string value based on a delimiter in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961996/how-to-split-a-string-value-based-on-a-delimiter-in-db2)

Comment: I want the String After first '/' and  The Second String  After Second '/' till First  ';'

Comment: As you said, credit is due. Welcome to upvote levels by the way!