# DB2 SQL to extract a string before and after a space or a character

Tags: sql, db2

I have a string which has spaces in full name. I want to extract first and last name.

For example, the displayname has firstname middlename lastname:

```
John D Cooper 
Mary L Finch
```

I want to get the result as shown below.

```
JohnCooper
MaryFinch
```

I am using passthrough to get into DB2 database and don't exactly know which function to use for that.

I use scan function in PROC SQL to get the result.

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
  select (scan(displayname,1,' ')||scan(displayname,-1,' ') as fullname 
  from have 
;
quit;
```

I appreciate any help with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get Substrings From DB2 Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52082300/get-substrings-from-db2-column)

Comment: Yes it did. I can get the data separated.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question for the next reader. The existing answers look correct also, it might just be a difference in db2 edition (i.e. luw/i/z)

Comment: WITH I(I) AS (VALUES
 ('John D Cooper') 
,('Mary L Finch') 
)
SELECT I, 
concat(SUBSTR(characters, 1, LOCATE(' ', characters) - 1) , 
  SUBSTR(characters, LOCATE(' ', characters, LOCATE(' ', characters) + 1) + 1)) 
      AS fullname
 FROM I ;

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this - it uses SUBSTR to extract the first word (everything to the first " " and concatenates it with a SUBSTR from the last space to the end)

```
select concat(
        substr(name, 1, locate_in_string(name, ' ', 1, 1, CODEUNITS32)-1) ,   
        substr(name, locate_in_string(name, ' ', -1, 1, CODEUNITS32)+1,length(name) - locate_in_string(name, ' ', -1, 1, CODEUNITS32)+1)
       ) 
 from table
```

Comment: I am getting following error.     
ERROR: CLI cursor extended fetch error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0138N  A numeric argument of a built-in string 
       function is out of range.  SQLSTATE=22011

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=b8eecb2163cec55bbe99d29c7c2e7f90

Answer (score 1):

Try using a regular expression.  E.g.

```
WITH I(I) AS (VALUES
 ('John D Cooper') 
,('Mary L Finch') 
)
SELECT I, REGEXP_REPLACE(I,'(\w+)\s+\w\s+(\w+)','\1\2') FROM I
```

will return

```
I            |2         
-------------|----------
John D Cooper|JohnCooper
Mary L Finch |MaryFinch
```

Comment: Paul, I am getting following error
ERROR: CLI describe error: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "REGEXP_REPLACE" of type 
       "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884

Comment: What Db2 version are you running? The REGEX functions came in Db2 (LUW) 11.1  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061496.html

Comment: FYI version 10.5 and earlier are no longer in (base) support https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/578841  so you should consider upgrading