# How to extract a value from a delimited string in Db2

Tags: db2

how to extract `PAXG` from the following string

```
0410|M|PAXG|20181114
```

in Db2 SQL

Comment: Welcome on SO, you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961996/how-to-split-a-string-value-based-on-a-delimiter-in-db2

Comment: The given value is stored in a variable of a table which is BILL how can I extract it from variable.

Comment: @JoeTaras I can't understand the reason of closing this question. All the answers in the mentioned posts don't use the ways described here, and they are very inefficient or not flexible and simple as these ones. All these old answers were written probably either when regexp-based functions were not available in Db2, or those writers were not aware of these functions.

Comment: @mustaccio I can't understand the reason of closing this question. All the answers in the mentioned posts don't use the ways described here, and they are very inefficient or not flexible and simple as these ones. All these old answers were written probably either when regexp-based functions were not available in Db2, or those writers were not aware of these functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for table `BILL` and its column `COL1` with data.

```
SELECT 
  COL1
-- since 9.7
, xmlcast(xmlquery('fn:tokenize($s, "\|")[3]' passing BILL.COL1 as "s") as varchar(20)) as one
-- since 11.1
, REGEXP_SUBSTR(BILL.COL1 || '|', '([^\|]*)\|', 1, 3, '', 1) as two
FROM 
(VALUES '0410|M|PAXG|20181114', '0410|M||20181114') BILL (COL1)
--BILL
;
```

Comment: The given value is stored in a variable of a table which is BILL how can I extract it from the variable.

Comment: Please, be more specific, when you ask questions. Use correct terminology. There is no such meaning as `variable`. There are `tables` and `columns`. `Statement` means SQL statement, and not something to extract data from. Provide the table and column name at least to not make others guess...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Db2 11.1 or above then `REGEXP_EXTRACT` will work for you.  E.g.

```
VALUES REGEXP_EXTRACT('0410|M|PAXG|20181114','([^\|]*)\|?', 1, 3, '', 1)
```

returns

```
1     
------
PAXG
```

[REGEXP_EXTRACT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0061492.html)

Comment: This doesn't work on an empty token. It should be a little bit different...

Comment: The 1-st argument should be externally closed by separator. You would not get the last token (4-th), if you needed it...

Comment: I've updated my code