# Passing comma separated vlaues to DB2 for IN Clause

Tags: c#, db2

I have a table valued function in DB2 which takes AddressCode as one of the parameters.  AddressCode is of type Char(50).

When I pass a single string value from my C# code like
AddressCode = "ABE001".  It works fine, however when i pass in two values

e.g.,

```
string mAddressCode = "M0044";
string bAddressCode = "B0608";    
string formattedAddressCode = mAddressCode + bAddressCode;
```

I get the following exception

```
$exception  {"ERROR [42601] [IBM][AS] SQL0104N  An unexpected token \"MUL0044\" was found following \"\".  Expected tokens may include:  \") ,\"."} IBM.Data.DB2.Core.DB2Exception
```

My where clause in Table Valued function looks like this

```
WHERE A . EMPSFT = 'Y' AND A . EMUKCD in ADDRESScODE
```

I would like to find out how to format the string to be used for IN Clause in DB2.

The following where clause works

```
WHERE A . EMPSFT = 'Y' AND A . EMUKCD in ('M0044','B0608')
```

The SQL script is passed to DB2 like so

```
  string formattedAddressCode =  string.Join(",", addressCode.Split(',').Select(x => $"'{x}'"));

  string sql = $"SELECT * FROM TABLE ( ABELIBLE.TVFBOEGETSHIPMENTS ( '{formattedStartDate}', '{formattedEndDate}' , '{formattedAddressCode}') )";
```

sql string looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ( ABELIBLE.TVFBOEGETSHIPMENTS ( '2020-07-06', '2020-08-05' , ''M0044','B0608'') )
```

Comment: You've got single quotes around the entire thing, so it will be `"'M0044, B0608//'"`.  You need to have `"','"` instead of `","` between them and it should end with `"'"`, not `"//'"`

Comment: There may be other problems as well, but we'd need to see the code you use to create your entire query string first.

Comment: If the error message is complaining about the M0044 being unexpected - that may indicate you are also missing the brackets/parentheses -('M0044','B0608')

Comment: It is useful for debugging to display (or log to a file in debugging mode) the FULL SQL query before submitting it to the database for execution.

Comment: @mao - I have updated my question now with the sql query which is being passed in from c#. Its almost like the quote are not in the right place.

Comment: For the IN list, the elements are delimited by ' (single-quote) and separated by comma. In your list, do you mean M0044 and B0608 to be __two__ elements or a single element,  and do quotes occurr in their values?

Comment: @mao - Thanks for your comment. I meant two elements. As in In('M0044','B0608'). Hope this answers your question.

Comment: If you pass a number of tokens in a single string, you must tokenize it. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61540876/10418264), for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps guys. I managed to fix it by changing my where clause to

```
    WHERE
            A . EMPSFT = 'Y'
            AND A . EMUKCD IN (
                SELECT regexp_substr(ADDRESSCODE,
                '[^,]+',
                1,
                LEVEL)
            FROM
                SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
            CONNECT BY
                regexp_substr(ADDRESSCODE,
                '[^,]+',
                1,
                LEVEL) IS NOT NULL)
```

Basically you need to do something like this

```
select regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES,sandhya, abe','[^,]+', 1, level) from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
  connect by regexp_substr('SMITH,ALLEN,WARD,JONES, sandhya, abe', '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null;
```

I got this from the following link
[Oracle link but modified it to suit DB2](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/how-to-split-comma-separated-string-and-pass-to-in-clause-of-select-statement)