# SQL: is it possible to select the substring after the last delimiter within a varchar column

Tags: sql, db2, substring

I'm trying to find a way to return a substring after the last delimiter of a varchar column.
The varchar column contains the content of a csv file, which is transferred between two applications.
The length of the last substring after the delimiter varies and contains up to three values, so that the sql
`select right(csv_content,10) from CSV_LINE`
doesn't retrieve the desired result.

Here is an example:
Table: CSV_Line

```
ID             trans_date      User        CSV_content
----------    -----------     --------     ------------
1             2020-03-15      user1        123456|987654|""|""|test|string|05678, 08798
2             2020-03-15      user2        123456|987654|""|""|test|string|15678, 08797, 03532
3             2020-03-14      user3        123456|987654|""|""|test|string|543218
```

what I want to do with is to get the last substring and to separate it where the comma is like that for example:

```
ID     value1          value2        value3
--    --------     ------------   ---------
1      05678           08798
2      15678           08797          03532
3      543218
```

I'm working on an IBM DB2 database.

Please can anyone help?

Comment: what platform and version of Db2?  Did you try searching for an answer?  What have you tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string value based on a delimiter in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961996/how-to-split-a-string-value-based-on-a-delimiter-in-db2)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regular expressions:

```
with data (id,str) as (values
(1, '123456|987654|""|""|test|string|05678, 08798'),
(2, '123456|987654|""|""|test|string|15678, 08797, 03532'),
(3, '123456|987654|""|""|test|string|543218')
)
select id,n,regexp_substr(str,'[0-9]+', 1, n)
from   (
    select id,regexp_substr(str,'(?<=\|)[^|]+$')
    from   data
) x (id,str)
cross  join (values (1),(2),(3)) y (n)
where  n <= regexp_count(str,'[0-9]+')
```