# how to split a string in stored procedure of DB2

Tags: stored-procedures, split, db2

I need split a string in DB2, my string is for example:

```
2660____,275____,10472316, ...
```

I need a loop to get all of the them, I know exists FOR in stored procedure DB2, But I can't use that

I write that for example:

```
FOR i AS mycursor CURSOR FOR SELECT SUBSTR(list, 1, LOCATE(',',list)-1) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1 do
    ...
END FOR;
```

But that doesn't work.

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string value based on a delimiter in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961996/how-to-split-a-string-value-based-on-a-delimiter-in-db2)

Comment: No, but thanks for answer. I want to have a loop for variable string

Comment: Your SELECT statement could look like the one under the "To tokenize a string" topic at the link above with `VALUES '2660____,275____,10472316, ...'` instead of that `VALUES` clause and "," instead of "-" (as string delimiter). And you may use a variable instead of the string constant, of course.

Comment: ```list``` in my code is a variable. can you write that in answer? in a loop please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following as specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61540876/10418264):

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_VAR VARCHAR (100);

  SET V_VAR = '2660____,275____,10472316';

  FOR C1 AS 
    SELECT TOK.TOKEN
    FROM 
      XMLTABLE
    (
      'for $id in tokenize($s, ",") return <i>{string($id)}</i>' PASSING V_VAR AS "s"
      COLUMNS
        SEQ   FOR ORDINALITY
      , TOKEN VARCHAR(20) PATH '.'
    ) TOK
    ORDER BY TOK.SEQ
  DO
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (C1.TOKEN);
  END FOR;

END
@
```