# How to use a string in Where in Clause?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, db2

I have a stored procedure which takes in a varchar(1000) whose value will be in the following format '0001,0002,0003,...'. There can be any number of comma separated codes in the string. Can this string in any way be used in a where in clause?

`Select * from class_codes where class_codes.codes in (codes_string)`

If not, what can we do to make this string useable in a where in clause?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string value based on a delimiter in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18961996/how-to-split-a-string-value-based-on-a-delimiter-in-db2)

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: If you are using sql 2016 version or later then you can use STRING_SPLIT Function

```
Select * from class_codes where class_codes.codes in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(codes_string, ','));
```

Method 2: If you are using sql versions less than 2016, then you can follow this method. You can create a function for string split as below and use it in the query as specified in the Method 1.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[STRING_SPLIT] 
( 
@InputString NVARCHAR(MAX), 
@delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(Value NVARCHAR(MAX) ) 
BEGIN 

DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @InputString) 

WHILE @start < LEN(@InputString) + 1 BEGIN 
    IF @end = 0  
        SET @end = LEN(@InputString) + 1
   
    INSERT INTO @output (Value)  
    VALUES(SUBSTRING(@InputString, @start, @end - @start)) 
    SET @start = @end + 1 
    SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @InputString, @start)
    
END 

RETURN 
END
```

And use this function in the query

```
Select * from class_codes where class_codes.codes in (SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(codes_string, ','));
```

Comment: OP uses Db2, not SQL Server.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).